# can't save my score - android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

First of all, i'm newbie.
I'm making an app in which you have 15 seconds to score as much as you can and then I want it to save your final score but I can't make it, here is the code:

```
package com.cannongaming.supertouch;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class StartActivity<TextView> 
                extends ActionBarActivity 
                implements OnClickListener {
    Button buttonTap, buttonLet;
    TextView textScore, textTime;
    int score=0;
    byte[] scoreBytes;
    String filename = "myscore";
    int timer = 15000; // 1000 = 1 second 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        //1
        buttonTap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTap);
        buttonLet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLet);
        textScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        textTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTime);
        scoreBytes[0] = (byte) score;
        scoreBytes[1] = (byte) (score >> 8);
        scoreBytes[2] = (byte) (score >> 16);
        ((android.widget.TextView) textTime).setText("00:00:15");

        //2
        ((android.widget.TextView) textScore).setText(String.valueOf(score));

        //3
        buttonTap.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonLet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(15000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        score++;
        ((android.widget.TextView) textScore).setText(String.valueOf(score));
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }});
    }
    public void onClick(View src){
        switch(src.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonTap:
            score++;
            ((android.widget.TextView) textScore).setText(String.valueOf(score));
            break;
        }
    }

    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            ((android.widget.TextView) textTime).setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FileOutputStream outputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(scoreBytes);
            outputStream.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

then i had 3 errors :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException  StartActivity.java  /SuperTouch/src/com/cannongaming/supertouch line 88 Java Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unhandled exception type IOException    StartActivity.java  /SuperTouch/src/com/cannongaming/supertouch line 89 Java Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unhandled exception type IOException    StartActivity.java  /SuperTouch/src/com/cannongaming/supertouch line 90 Java Problem
```

and then i've changed my `onFinish` to this:

```
public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(scoreBytes);
        outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

and there are no errors anymore but when I open my app, it says it's forced to close. Please help me!

Comment: You can save your score with SharedPreferences in XML file. You do not need file operations. SharedPreferences is more efficient.

Comment: Do you have any Logcat errors???

Comment: if i use shared preferences will i be able to load it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mitigated a compilation error via placing the catch.

The problem you are facing now is for sure `NullPointerException` as long as you declare `byte[] scoreBytes;`, but do not initialize it anywhere below. Make the decalration like so and you will be one exception further:

```
byte[] scoreBytes = new byte[3];
```

**EDIT**

And now come the advises:

- Log the exceptions apprpriately. I always advise towards using the android tooling for tracking the exceptions, rather than dumping them to the console. Thus I would recommend you to replace this line of your refactored solution:

  ```
  e.printStackTrace();
  ```

  To this one:

  ```
  Log.e("TAG", "An exception while opoening the output file", e);
  ```
- try to figure out the problems by yourself. Look at the stacktraces in the Logcat. The logcat is one of the most important android views in Eclipse. If you do not see it by default, visualise it via going to Window -> Other -> android -> Logcat. It will display the erorrs that happen in your code (like the thing that is currently failing you)